# Constructor ambiguity with varargs in java 8

Tags: java

In the class below, I get a compilation error with Java 8 due to an ambiguous call to `this()`. With Java 6 this class compiled fine, though.
I know I could refactor this using factory methods and such but for the actual class where the problem occurs, I would strongly prefer to maintain the current API for now.

Can anyone think of a way to resolve the ambiguity without changing the external API?

```
public class Vararg8 {

    public Vararg8(final Object... os) {}

    public Vararg8(final boolean b,
                   final String s,
                   final int... is) {}

    public Vararg8() {
        this(true, "test", 4, 5, 6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it by passing an explicit `int[]` array:

```
public Vararg8()
{
  this(true, "test", new int[]{4, 5, 6});
}
```

You might notice that this is still, in one sense, ambiguous: what you've passed is still compatible with the `Object...` constructor. The reason this works is that method resolution goes in various stages, and only the last stage allows consideration of varargs parameters. Because you've used an explicit array, it hits the second one fine without needing varargs expansion. It can't hit the first one without varargs expansion, so that wouldn't be considered till the final stage.

See [the appropriate JLS docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>
> The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the JLS reference. I didn't know about this multi-stage resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public Vararg8()
{
  this(true, "test", new int[]{4, 5, 6});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an explicit int array should solve your problem.

```
  public Vararg8() {
        this(true, "test",new int[]{ 4, 5, 6});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic to infer the types at runtime, but this will transform them to Boxed form. This of course is performance kamikaze, if you do a lot of arithmetic in there or have to box a lot of primitives, but would leave all existing code working fine.

If you are using Objects types already, then this solution will cost you nothing.

This would look likes this:

```
public<A extends Boolean, B extends String, C extends Integer> Disambiguate(final A booleanPar,
                                        final B stringPar,
                                        final C... integerPar) {System.out.println("Im in the specific one");}

public<T extends Object> Disambiguate(final T... os) {System.out.println("Im in the general one");}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Disambiguate(true, "test", 4, 5, 6);
}
```

You could use generics for "backward compatibility" with 1.5 and higher and leave all existing code working fine and make a new Api, that will avoid the problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Character array also solve your problem

```
public Vararg8() {
            this(true, "test".toCharArray(), 4, 5, 6);
        }
```

Comment: The types in the example were just an illustration, the actual code used mostly domain specific types...